# Thinning algorithm in Octave, index error

Tags: octave

I'm trying to code the [Zhang Suen thinning algorithm](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Zhang-Suen_thinning_algorithm) using Octave. I'm not used at using Octave and I corrected many errors already, but there is this `error: imgSeuil(0,_): subscripts must be either integers 1 to (2^63)-1 or logicals` which explains that i'm trying to access a pixel of the image using incorrect index, but I didn't find how to correct it. The mistake is probably obvious, I just need a fresh look at it. Here is some code:

```
        clear all;
        close all;
        
        img=imread("ED_3_6_originale.png");
        imshow(img);
        colorbar();
        
        sizeImg = size(img);
        NL=sizeImg(1,1);
        NC=sizeImg(1,2);
        
        tab=zeros(2,256); %grey lvl table
        tab(1,1:256)=0:255;
        
        %Grey level table and
        %chart printing
        for y=1:NL
            for x= 1:NC
                val=img(y,x);
                tab(2,val+1)=tab(2,val+1)+1;
            end
        end
        
        ticktab=zeros(1,25);
        
        for i=1:25
            ticktab(1, i)=10*i;
        end
        
        figure(2);
        plot(tab(1, 1:256),tab(2, 1:256));
        set(gca,'XTick',ticktab(1, 1:25));
        xlim([0, 255]);
        %seuillage de l'img
        figure(3);
        imgSeuil=img;
        for y=1:NL
            for x= 1:NC
                val=imgSeuil(y,x);
                if(val<30)
                    imgSeuil(y,x)=0;
                else
                    imgSeuil(y,x)=255;
                end
            end
        end
        imgSeuil=~imgSeuil;%inversion pour lignes blanches
        imshow(imgSeuil);
        
    
        %%%--------------
        
        %%stopCond=1;
        %%while stopCond = 1
          ap1 = 0;
          bp1 = 0;
          tabPixel = zeros(2,1);
          for x=2:NL-1
              for y= 2:NC-1
                p1 = imgSeuil(x,y);
                p2 = imgSeuil(x-1, y);
                p3 = imgSeuil(x-1, y+1);
                p4 = imgSeuil(x, y+1);
                p5 = imgSeuil(x+1, y+1);
                p6 = imgSeuil(x+1, y);
                p7 = imgSeuil(x+1, y-1);
                p8 = imgSeuil(x, y-1);
                p9 = imgSeuil(x-1, y-1);
                tabNeighbour = [p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9];
                tmpTabl = diff([tabNeighbour, p2]);
                tmpTabl = max(tmpTabl, 0);
                ap1 = sum(tmpTabl);
                bp1 = sum(tabNeighbour);
                
        ##        disp(bp1);
                if((p1==0)&&(bp1>=2)&&(bp1<=6)&&(ap1==1)&&
                  ((p2==1)||(p4==1)||(p6==1))&&
                  ((p4==1)||(p6==1)||(p8==1)))
                    tabPixel = [tabPixel, [x; y]];
                  endif
              endfor
          endfor
        ##  disp(tabPixel);
          for i=1:columns(tabPixel)
%%---------Error occurs on the next line ------%%
            imgSeuil(tabPixel(1, i), tabPixel(2, i)) = 255;
          endfor
       %%endwhile
```

The first step begins after `%%%-----`, I didn't include the second because it's almost the same.
The first lines are basically just printing the original picture, use a threshold to make it binary instead of grey scale.

Comment: On what line does the error occur? It's not clear from what you posted. `imgSeuil(0, _ )` suggests you're attempting to index the zeroth row, which, as the error tells you, doesn't exist. What probably happens, is that `tabPixel(1,1)` is **zero** as per your definition. You're using that as an index into your image, which indeed errors out.

Comment: Thank you for your help Adriaan, tabPixel should be filled with indexes of the pixels matching all the tests before, and I do not go on the border of the image so 0 doesnt seem possible. I thought I might be scanning the table in the wrong way so i'm trying this right now. Is it possible to have this error happen with an index out of bound  ?

Comment: 0 cannot be your border, as Octave uses 1-based indexing. Your borders will thus be `img(1,:); image(end,:); image(:,1); image(:,end)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `i = 1` in your last loop, you're indexing `imgSeuil(tabPixel(1, 1), tabPixel(2, 1))`, which evaluates to `imgSeuil(0, 0)`, which is indeed impossible to index. You'll need to change how you define it. Judging your code, either initialising as `tabPixel = []`, i.e. empty, or letting your final `for` loop run from `i = 2` (or even removing the first column of `tabPixel` after your nested `for` loop), will all do the trick.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I changed `tabPixel = []` because I had an error of dimension not matching when trying to append [x;y]. Much appreciated :)